# Simple box in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I hope someone can help me.Well I want to make a html/css box with an image and some text within it.It is all described in the picture below..

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  http://whathaveyoutried.com? Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please see [the Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<div class="outer">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300"></img>
    <div class="centered">Text here centered</div>
    <div>Some text some text some text some text</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.outer{
   border: dashed 1px grey;
    width:200px;
}
.centered{
    background-color:skyblue;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Demo:<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/fTXf3/1/</kbd>